# How to convert list without generics to list with generics using streams in java?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I would like convert a `List` without generics to `List<MyConcreteType>`.

I also need to filter out only my concrete types.

My current stream logic is like:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
Object collect1 = list.stream().filter((o -> o instanceof MyConcreteType)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But as a result I'm getting an `Object` instead of a `List`. Is there a way to convert this `Stream` to a `List<MyConcreteType>`?

Comment: Just cast it `List<MyConcreteType> typedList = (List<MyConcreteType>) list`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider but I need to filter it first - cause it can contain other items as well

Comment: `list.stream().filter(MyConcreteType.class::isInstance).map(MyConcreteType.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList())` then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use parameterized types instead of raw types, and use `map` to cast the objects that pass the filter to `MyConcreteType`:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList();
List<MyConcreteType> collect1 = 
    list.stream()
        .filter((o -> o instanceof MyConcreteType))
        .map(s-> (MyConcreteType) s)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or (similar to what Boris suggested in comment):

```
 List<?> list = new ArrayList();
 List<MyConcreteType> collect1 = 
     list.stream()
         .filter(MyConcreteType.class::isInstance)
         .map(MyConcreteType.class::cast)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```